# Thinktecture identity server 3 Single Sign Out

Tags: single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server

I hope some one point me towards right direction.
I have setup Identity server 3 on IIS and 2 different MVC clients to this Identity server.
I am little confused about SIngle Sign out. I was hoping to achieve single sign out.
However when i login, each client web site setup its own aspNet session cookie.
When i logout from one client, the other client still retain its session(because of its own session cookie).
How can i achieve Single sign out for multiple applications with different domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenID Connect spec for single sign-out hasn't yet been published/completed. It's still a work in progress here: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

IdentityServer does support part of the sign-out though. You need to make a sign-out request to the OP via the end_session_endpoint URL that's in the metadata.